# Weblogic Create 2 data sources

Tags: java, weblogic

I am using weblogic server for my application.
There are 2 data sources that I can use
1. localhost
2. dev

My question is can I create 2 data sources and use them for local testing. I have one domain.

I get an error if I do that;
Error Failed to bind remote object (ClusterableRemoteRef(-8493092708980746818S::base_domain:AdminServer null)/881   [weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RemoteDataSource]) to replica aware stub at MyDataSource(ClusterableRemoteRef(-8493092708980746818S::base_domain:AdminServer [-8493092708980746818S::base_domain:AdminServer/287])/287   [weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RemoteDataSource])

Comment: Yes, you can add more than one data sources to a weblogic domain.

Comment: Actually I got an error while doing that...Error Failed to bind remote object (ClusterableRemoteRef(-8493092708980746818S::base_domain:AdminServer null)/881 [weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RemoteDataSource]) to replica aware stub at MyDataSource(ClusterableRemoteRef(-8493092708980746818S::base_domain:AdminServer [-8493092708980746818S::base_domain:AdminServer/287])/287 [weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RemoteDataSource])

Answer (score 9):

Please make sure that these two data sources you're creating **DO NOT** have the same **name** *OR* **JNDI name** (I've seen this error when accidentally trying to create a data source that already existed)

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same exception. The solution was to add one datasource -> Activate Changes, then shut down Weblogic, start again, add the second datasource -> Activate Changes -> works.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the answer from Rafael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17595817/2446208), make sure that you don't accidentally have a new line in your JNDI name block. You can double check this by checking the `<your domain>/config/jdbc/<your datasource name>.xml` file and ensure you don't have two `jndi-name` fields like the following:

```
<jndi-name>jdbc/mydatasource</jndi-name>
<jndi-name></jndi-name>
```

Removing the `jndi-name` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You can have a datasource with the same jndi name, just not targeted. Untarget the datasource with the same jndi name and then create your datasource.

Ensure you save your changes.